# AWS Lambda: Is there a way to "Drip feed" a batch of messages to a Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm looking for a way to "drip-feed" Lambda executions (beyond what's possible with "reserved concurrent executions").

I'm looking to have one event processed at a time, at no more than a 30s interval. I have a downstream database that needs to do a bunch of processing, such that if more than one event is processed within a 30s window, processing will overlap and the contents of the database risk getting into a muddle.

The order isn't an issue, neither is the total time to process (within reason). The important thing is to make sure only one update is processed at a time.

The outline of the process I'm trying to achieve is:

- Data file(s) arrive in s3 (anything from 1 to 1000s) at any time (and batches may overlap)
- Lambda processes files one-by-one, min. 30s interval
- As a result, RDS processes only one update at a time so that data doesn't get muddled.

So far I have:

- Files arrive in s3, triggering a "receiver" function
- Receiver function writes "to-do" records into Dynamodb, pings a message onto a queue and exits.
- The message sent to the queue triggers a second "processor" function
- The processor function processes one record from Dynamo
- If there are more records left to process, the processor function pings a message to the same queue (with a 30s delivery delay) to trigger itself in the future

That gets me pretty close. The issue I foresee is that if another batch of files lands in the middle of a first batch being processed, I would get a second "ping" which would trigger an overlapping execution.

I've looked at de-duplication, but it looks like that has a 5-minute window, which would probably slow down the execution cycle too much (30s is fine, 1000 files processed in ~8h. 5m would push that to ~3.5 days which is too slow)

I sense there's a simple, neat solution to "drip feed messages at 30s intervals" but I've not yet found it!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this is to send your messages to an SQS queue, but do not enable the SQS integration with Lambda. Instead, have your Lambda function [run on a schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-expressions.html), like every 60 seconds. When the Lambda function starts, have it use the AWS SDK to attempt to retrieve one message from the SQS queue, then send the message to the database, and finally delete the message from the SQS queue.